# System of differential equations in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation

> Let $f (x)=x^2e^{-x} $. Determine the solution $u (x,t) $ of the system of equations$$\partial^2_xu=\frac 1 k \partial_tu$$ $$u (x,0)=f (x),$$ for a constant $k $.

Is there a particular way to resolve this problem? I don't have anything similar in my notes, and I didn't have an intuition by myself. Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: This is a one-dimensonal heat equation. You are solving the initial value problem for it. The solution  is given by the convolution with the fundamental solution, which is  a Gaussian (you can absorb the $k$ factor into $\partial_t u$ first to get the clean version of the equation if you prefer to). Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation under "Fundamental solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial^2_xu=\frac 1 k \partial_tu \\
 u (x,0)=f (x)
\end{cases}
$$
For the Heat's Equation, you can use what you have recently learned, the Fourier Transform.
$$
\begin{cases}
\hat u''(\omega,t)-i\omega \frac 1 k\hat u(\omega,t)  =0 \\
 \hat u (\omega,0)=\hat f (\omega) \text {, where } \hat f (\omega)=\omega ^2 e^{-\omega}
\end{cases}
$$ 
Now you have a second order linear differential equation. you should be able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, probably this is the method I'm supposed to use. However I don't understand well what is $\hat {u}(\omega, t)$: I think it is the Fourier transform of the two variable function $u $, but then I don't see why you added the term $i\omega $ only when you derived respect to $t $, and didn't add anything when you derived respect to $\omega $

Comment: Where are you stuck with the differential equation @Dorian ?

Comment: Now it is clear, thank you anyway

Comment: yw @Dorian......